# JavaScript, 'this' reference, when calling object function from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, this

Here is a simplified version of my JS:

```
var myObject = function() {
    return {
        functionOne: function() {
            //some other logic here
        },
        functionTwo: function() {
            var self = this;
            //some logic here
            //then call functionOne
            self.functionOne();
        }
    };
}
```

Then I have this in the body of my html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myObject.functionTwo()">click me</a>
```

Why do I get the error *Uncaught TypeError: Object [some url] has no method 'functionOne'*, when I click the link?

Comment: *"has no method 'functionOne'"*? You sure about that? You're trying to invoke `functionTwo`, which should fail.

Comment: I have a feeling that you have `();` at the end of your assignment, and you're trying to pass `self.functionOne` somewhere to be invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you're seeing doesn't reflect the example code you've shown.

That said, in the way that you're using the code, you should be able to reduce it to simply:

```
var myObject = {
    functionOne: function() {
    },
    functionTwo: function() {
        this.functionOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: `myObject` doesn't need to be invoked as a constructor. It just needs to be invoked.

Comment: @user1689607 But if you just invoke it, `this` will reference `window` and that makes even less sense :)

Comment: But `this` isn't used anywhere in the `myObject` function. It just returns a plain object that has methods. Those methods have `this`, which will be a reference to the plain object if they're invoked from that object. So doing `myObject().functionTwo()` will work.

Comment: @user1689607 Hmm, you're right. I kept thinking `this` should reference instances of `myObject` :)

Comment: You're right. I apologize; I got the wrong error message somehow. I made it simpler too :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `myObject` is a **function** that needs to be **called** in order to get that object

```
<a href="#" onclick="myObject().functionTwo()">click me</a>
```

Why not just define `myObject` as an object:

```
var myObject = {
    functionOne: function() {
        //some other logic here
    },
    functionTwo: function() {
        var self = this;
        //some logic here
        //then call functionOne
        self.functionOne();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is for your function to be executed immediately. Further to that your declarion of the **self** variable leads me to think that you are trying to create a closure so that you can access functionOne from functionTwo. If that is the case then I think the following is what you were after:

```
var myObject = (function() {

    function func1( ) {
    }

    function func2( ) {
        func1();
    }
    return {
        functionOne: func1,
        functionTwo: func2
    };
}());
```